# MySQLi not working using INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I submit the below it does not error out but it also does not insert the data into the table. I am a beginner in php so have mercy.

```
<?php
/* include_once 'dbconn.php';*/
include 'menu.php';
error_reporting(0);
?>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="add_student.php" method="post">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br/>
        School:<input type="text" name="school"><br/>
        PR:<input type="text" name="pr"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
<?php
$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "root";
$DB_name = "trackmeet";

$MySQLiconn = new MySQLi($DB_host,$DB_user,$DB_pass,$DB_name);

if($MySQLiconn->connect_errno)
{
    die("ERROR : -> ".$MySQLiconn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student(Student,School,PR) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[school]','$_POST[pr])";
    mysqli_query($sql,$MySQLiconn);
    mysqli_close($MySQLiconn);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I look in the database table the record was not inserted.

Comment: I moved the $_POST but still does not show in the database.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO student(Student,School,PR) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[school]','$_POST[pr]')";
    mysqli_query($sql,$MySQLiconn);

    mysqli_close($MySQLiconn);
}
?>
    <form action="add_student.php" method="post">
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br />
        School:<input type="text" name="school"><br />
        PR:<input type="text" name="pr"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
Still does not show up in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

```
mysqli_query($sql,$MySQLiconn);
```

changed to

```
$sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);
```

Thanks for the help. Nice to have people out there that are willing to teach people like me.

Answer (score 1):

You have typo missing this in query ' on value `$_POST[pr]`
original:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student(Student,School,PR) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[school]','$_POST[pr])";
mysqli_query($sql,$MySQLiconn);
```

fixed:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student(Student,School,PR) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[school]','$_POST[pr]')";
mysqli_query($sql,$MySQLiconn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the order of your parameters wrong;

```
mysqli_query($sql,$MySQLiconn);
```

should be

```
mysqli_query($MySQLiconn,$sql);
```

or use the object orientated method if you so wish

```
$MySQLiconn->query($sql);
```